# Problem building webpart using WSPBuilder

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, gac, wspbuilder

I have tried creating several web parts using Visual Studio 2010 using available guides for WSPBuilder but I always get the error:

WSPBuilder
Version: 1.0.9.1118
Created by Carsten Keutmann
GPL License 2007
Building the solution - please wait
**Can not find the defined Project Assembly : c:\documents and settings\adm_marcus\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestWSP\TestWSP\GAC\TestWSP.dll**
Solution compatibility: SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010
Saving the Manifest.xml file
Creating the WSP file
Cleanup
Done!

If I then deploy I can see it in the GAC using the Solutions Manager but it doesn't show as available when trying to add it to the Web Parts Gallery. I have made an IIS-reset every time after deployment.

Also, WSPBuilder doesn't create a 12-folder. Instead I get a SharepointRoot folder.

Does anyone have any clue of what the problem can be?

Comment: Are you trying to build web parts for SharePoint 2007 or 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really quite stupid of me. I thought that I should only use the build process under the WSPBuild menu. When I used the regular menu's Build first and then WSPBuilder's Build I didn't get this message anymore. Then I got another error message regarding unmanaged code and I had to change target framework to C# 3.5.